# Confused at notation $h(x,y,z)=f(u(x,y,z),v(x,y,z),w(x,y,z))$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $h(x,y,z)=f(u(x,y,z),v(x,y,z),w(x,y,z))$ find $h_x,h_y,h_z$.

Let
$$f(u,v,w)=u^2+v^2-w$$

$u(x,y,z)=x^2y, v(x,y,z)=y^2, w(x,y,z)=e^{-xz}$.

I don't understand this question, I think $h_x$ should be the same as $f_x$ and so on but I'm not really sure.

Could someone clarify this? Does the fact that "f depends on u,v,w and h on x,y,z" change anything?

E: for

Comment: Sicne the name of the arguments of $f$ are $u,v,w$, I don't think $f_x$ means anything to anyone else. $f_u$ is the partial derivative with regard to its first argument, $f_v$ its partial derivative with regards to its second argument etc. Once you consider changing the arguments without changing the name of the functions, it gets really confusing, that's why the function is called $h(x,y,z)$ and not $f(x,y,z)$.

Comment: $f_x$ should be $f_u u_x+ f_v...$ am I mistaken?

Comment: that's not $f_x$ that's $h_x$

Comment: $x$ is not the name of an argument of $f$ so $f_x$ DOESNT MAKE SENSE. Here in mathematics we don't play the silly game of trying to guess what arguments goes into what expression. $f$ has $3$ arguments $u,v,w$, so $f$ has $3$ partial derivatives along $u,v,w$. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: if you had $h(u,x) = f(u,v(u,x))$ then "your" $f_u$ would mean two different things at once and we don't like that here.

Comment: I don't get how what I wrote isn't $f_x$ I just applied the chain rule...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Because of the chain rule it is (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChainRule.html for example)

$$h_x=f_uu_x+f_vv_x+f_ww_x.$$ Now use that $$f_u=2u,f_v=2v, f_w=-1$$ and $$u_x=2xy,v_x=0, w_x=-ze^{-xz}.$$

Comment: Hmm isn't $h_x=f_x$?

Comment: In general the answer is no. Consider $h(x)=f(x^2).$ It is: $h'(x)=2xf'(x)\ne f'(x).$

Comment: I got $h_x=4x^3y^2+ze^{-xz}$ is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Proceed in the same way to get $h_y$ and $h_z.$

Comment: In this particular case, $h_x=f_x$, right?

Comment: What do you mean by $f_x?$ If you mean the partial derivative with respect to the first variable, then $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z$ and $f_x=2x\ne h_x.$

Comment: By $f_x$ i mean $\frac {\partial f }{\partial u}\frac {\partial u}{\partial x}$...

Comment: This is not $f_x.$ It is $h_x.$ $f$ depends on $u,v,w.$ Now, if $u,v,w$ depends on $x$ then the new function $h(x)=f(u(x),v(x),w(x))$ depends on $x.$ But not $f.$